# What it is a soft variable?

Tags: linux, centos6

I am trying to understand this fragment from the benchmark of CentOs6' guide Hardering but I'm not been success yet... Can anybody explain me what it is a soft variable?

The context where is said is the next:

"Setting a hard limit on core dumps prevents users from overriding the soft variable. If core dumps are required, consider setting limits for user groups (see limits.conf(5)). In addition, setting the fs.suid_dumpable variable to 0 will prevent setuid programs from dumping core [...]"

Page 39 from Hardering Guide of CentOs6

Thank you so much!

Comment: This question would probably be better on Super User. http://superuser.com/ Anyway, how I read this is that you can set hard limits which are limits that the users cannot overstep, where the soft-variable is something that normal users can access and set that will not be able to supersede the hard limit. So, for example say you use a hard core limit of  `N kB` the soft variable core limit will be limited to `=< N kB`

Comment: I don't exacly understand the example of the soft variable; I understand the concept of hard limit but when/how is supose to use the soft v.Thank you very much for your answer and the tipo of supersuser.

Comment: Here read this: http://linux.die.net/man/5/limits.conf it helps explain hard v. soft.

Comment: Thank you again! That's much helpful

Answer (score 0):

Here read this: [linux.die.net/man/5/limits.conf](http://linux.die.net/man/5/limits.conf) it helps explain hard v. soft. – Tom Myddeltyn

Answer (score 0):

A "soft" limit is one that you may decrease or increase (up to the "hard" limit), and a "hard" limit is one that you can't increase.

Initial limits are imposed by the system configuration.  See the `limits.conf` manual.

See also the entry for the `ulimit` builtin of your particular shell.